# multiple vhosts for mod_jk going to tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

small configuration problem here.  i have a tomcat server with apps deployed like this

```
tomcat.mydomain.com:8080/app1
tomcat.mydomain.com:8080/app2
tomcat.mydomain.com:8080/app3
tomcat.mydomain.com:8080/app4
tomcat.mydomain.com:8080/app5
```

because of other reasons, i have to use mod_jk to proxy these applications out to the following urls

```
myapp1.mydomain.com
myapp2.mydomain.com
myapp3.mydomain.com
myapp4.mydomain.com
www.completedifferentdomain.com
```

ive been searching online for ideas how to configure this but it looks like i have to map the individual applications to their own subdomain in tomcat and then proxy to those subdomains.  is that correct or can i do this some other way.

Comment: What are you using to host this?  I know Ubuntu has tools to support multiple tomcats running at one time (I have 9 on one server at this point).

Comment: its hosted on a debian server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case anyone cares, i ended up having to configure all the applications into their own vhosts and then mapping them thru the proxy.  there probably is a better way to do it, but i was under the gun and that was the only configuration i had that worked.

Comment: +1 for self empowerment! BTW, that is the way I would've done it myself. Based on what you stated, vhosts going to be cleaner and easier to manage.